# Why is it not possible to access a public website?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xhtml, msxml, queryselector

This url can not be opened with URL-copy&paste it shows only an error. I have tried in vain to get access through MSXML2.XMLHTTP, same result!

This is my code:

Sub GetDataWebsite()

```
Const URL = "http://Zvg-port.de/index.php"
Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument
Dim elmt As Object
Dim x As Long

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    .Open "POST", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send         
    HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    
End With
           
Set elmt = HTML.querySelectorAll("tr")   'or any class or tag or name

For x = 0 To elmt.Length - 1

    ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 2) = elmt.Item(x).innerText

Next x
```

End Sub

Nothing happens! What could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: What are you searching for? Are there specific search terms that are supposed to go in the search box on the website?

Comment: So if you were searching on the actual webpage would you enter Norderstedt Schleswig-Holstein as place?

Comment: Please give me a link I can visit and tell me what values I need to enter & where before hitting search.

Comment: I can solve your first problem with vba. So far I can only solve your second problem with other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you need to add additional parameters to the initial request body.
Weirdly, one has to keep working off `html`,  rather than setting anything into derived variables, if one wants to use `querySelectorAll()`.

For your second question, the result urls are expected to be navigated to after coming from the search page. A little testing indicates a `referer` header is needed. I know an request, with/without html session, with `referer` header will work because I tested with Python, but I haven't worked out what the missing bit is for VBA; my current attempts are returning odd encoding that also looks truncated.

Currently, **the easiest way I see, if sticking with VBA, to ensure following links, would be to automate a browser**, gather the results and the result links, then navigate to each link.

---

Current code (which answers your first question):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetDataZvgPort()

    Const URL = "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen"
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
   
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    
    Dim headers As Variant
    
    With xhr
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "land_abk=sh&ger_name=Norderstedt&order_by=2&ger_id=X1526"
        headers = .getAllResponseHeaders
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
 
    Dim x As Long, link As String, gatheredLinks()

    ReDim gatheredLinks(html.querySelectorAll("td a").Length - 1)
    
    For x = 0 To html.querySelectorAll("table a nobr").Length - 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 2) = html.querySelectorAll("table a nobr").Item(x).innerText
        link = Replace$(html.querySelectorAll("td a").Item(x).href, "about:", "https://www.zvg-portal.de/")
        ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 3) = link
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 0 To html.querySelectorAll("tr").Length - 1
            If InStr(html.querySelectorAll("tr").Item(j).innerHTML, "Amtsgericht") > 0 Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 4) = html.querySelectorAll("tr").Item(j).getElementsByTagName("b")(0).innerText
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        gatheredLinks(x) = link
    Next x
    
'    With xhr
'        For x = LBound(gatheredLinks) To UBound(gatheredLinks)
'            .Open "GET", gatheredLinks(x), False
'            .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen"
'            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
'            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "python-requests/2.24.0"
'            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
'            .setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
'            .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;"
'            .send
'            ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 5) = .Status
'            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText 'test response
'            Dim s As String
'            s = .responseText
'            ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 6) = s
'            Stop
'
'            'do something else
'        Next
'    End With
    Stop
    
End Sub
```

---

**Python (using session) which can successfully retrieve content from result links:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = {'ger_name': 'Norderstedt','order_by': '2','land_abk': 'sh','ger_id': 'X1526'}

headers = {'Referer': 'https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    
    r = s.post('https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen', data=data)
    print(r.status_code)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = ['https://www.zvg-portal.de/' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('td a')]
    s.headers = headers
    
    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        # print(r.status_code)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        print(soup.select_one('td p').text)
```

Session is **NOT** required. It is used just for efficiency.

Without a session, which still works, the headers sent are:

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Referer': 'https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen'}
```

Comment: I have updated so you can see it returns Norderstedt. For the links bit still need to work that out. To integrate python with excel you can use xlwings or call  a python script from vba that outputs data as csv to a folder location.

Comment: Mr. QHarr, while I don't know who you are, I appreciate you going to so much trouble to help me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I installed Python, saved the above Python code (the one without a session)  as a .py file on my desktop, then have written this script in Excel VBA:

`Sub RunPythonScript()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
PythonExe = """C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"""
PythonScript = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ExcelPythonTest01.py"
objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
End Sub`

when I start the sub in excel, winshell opens, closes right away and nothing else happens! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ...about voting: " stackoverflow: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Yes. You can accept any answer as you posted it but there is a min rep requirement for upvotes.

Comment: With respect to your python you may need to add a command line flag to keep the console open. I will see if I can dig something up.

Comment: Thanks...voting = accepting? I'll keep doing that :-)  Could you find a way to open the second page "zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=showZvg&zvg_id=754&land_abk=sh" ?

Comment: Voting is not the same as accepting. See the original link. WriteTxtFile line removed. That is for my debugging purposes and should not have been included. The commented out lines were my experimenting with solving the second quesiton.

Comment: OK, now i found the accept button! Thanks for the note.

Comment: It's an either or in my opinion. If you have python installed why not do the whole thing with python? I can add a couple of lines which write the output to csv? You can then run the script from cmd if on windows; bash/terminal; or IDLE; or literally sooooo many places e.g. visual studio code/IDLE...........

Comment: Python can generate the csv then you load the csv into Access.

Comment: With python you would do everything with python and not the browser.

Comment: When I try to print the whole content of the website with modified **Python (using session)-code**  `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") print(soup.content)`  I only get "NONE". Any solution?

Comment: your code above; **Python (using session) which can successfully retrieve content from result links**, just modified your last row `print(soup.select_one('td p').text)`  to `print(soup.content)`. Result in Python IDLE: **NONE**

Comment: I'll look over weekend

Comment: .content is usually for when working off response not soup. soup.content assumes a content tag being present. Instead `print(soup)`

Comment: Thanks & have a nice weekend